# How to add a custom field in product_form.xml

Tags: magento2

How to add a custom field in product_form.xml, or rather, to the 'Search Engine Optimization' section.
[image]

Comment: Any news about your issue? Check my answer bellow, I think is the best way to get it. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

It is some special when create product form. Magento did not use XML file to create form. They have used "`Modifier Class`" to create them.
You can find some construction inside `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier` folder. If you just want to add a new text field inside product_form. Add the following code:

Create **SearchEngineCustomization** class in **Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier** and add the code below:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;

class SearchEngineCustomization extends AbstractModifier
{
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta) {
        $meta = [
            'search-engine-customization' => [
                'children' => [
                    'container_custom_field' => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'label' => __('Custom Field'),
                                    'required' => 0,
                                    'componentType' => 'container',
                                    'formElement' => 'container',
                                    'sortOrder' => 0
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        'children' => [
                            'custom_field' => [
                                'argements' => [
                                    'data' => [
                                        'config' => [
                                            'dataType' => 'text',
                                            'formElement' => 'input',
                                            'visible' => 1,
                                            'label' => 'Custom Field',
                                            'componentType' => 'field',
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
        return $meta;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data) {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

After modify the class, add it to your product_form by **adminhtml\di.xml**:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pool" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="search-engine-customization" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\SearchEngineCustomization</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Hope it useful!

Comment: Many thanks, but there's something missing in your code. I receive an error: "The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "search-engine-customization" component."

Comment: I have tired this code, but the values are not saved in the database. Do I have to create the fields manually in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new filed just in there, in SEO group, but I did it with installData script of my module, in other words, I use the existent magento EAV, so I've created a new attribute to the product, exactly the same way you can do manually on admin panel, I just don't know how to set your new attribute to "SEO" Group in product form when it is manually created, but in code, is like this: **app/code/YourVendor/YurModule/Setup/installData.php**

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    /**
     * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
     */
    $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'your_filed_code');
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'your_filed_code',
        [
            //here you set the group, in this case this new field will apper on "SEO" group
            'group' => 'Search Engine Optimization',
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Your Field Name',
            'input' => 'text',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
  }
}
```

And then you change the `Your Field Name` to your field name and `your_filed_code` to your field code. This script will run when you install your module, with the comand `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and will adds your custom field on your products form. I hope it helps.